How to implement Spark Microsystems UWB SDK on a board with STM32 chip? Understanding the workflow/toolchain
I am a novice programmer with a pretty challenging task. The set up is as follows - I have a custom board with STM32 chip, the chip is connected to another ultra wide band (UWB, Spark Microsystems) chip. THe STM32 chip is programmed with ST’s STM32CubeMX (initial setup) and for UWB I am tying to implement some example programs that came with the  UWB SDK (CMakeLists.txt files are included in SDK). From CubeMX I am able to export to ST’s CubeIDE (Makerfile and CMake options are also available). Question I am faced with - should I implement (learn how to) UWB demo programs in STM32CubeIDE or is there another workflow you could suggest? Thank you!
As a beginner programmer I am doing research on toolchain to figure out the correct workflow and tools that need to be learned.
